# PictureBox at Click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources, onclick

i have create this code for my button but the image doesen't change why?

```
private void pictureBox94_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox94.Image == Properties.Resources.vuoto)
            {
                pictureBox94.Image = Properties.Resources.select;
                checkBox3.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox94.Image = Properties.Resources.vuoto;
                checkBox3.Checked = false;
            }
        }
```

any error!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the start of the `if` statement and traced the execution path through the code? I would predict that it is always going through the *false* clause, so your picture is not *appearing* to change.

Comment: help me please whats false clause?

Comment: The `else` part of the `if` statement, the part that is executed if the expression evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I don't believe the `==` is comparing the images.  It's probably checking whether they are the same object, which will never be true.

Comment: I dont find the -1 fair, it is not obvious that a call to `Properties.Resources.vuoto` always returns a new `Image` instance (I had to check for myself). If it wouldn't, the code should work. This behaviour is not expected for more or less "constant" properties like resources, so others may run into the same troubles. Hence my +1 (I find the question useful for others...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactor your method to be check weather the check box is checked instead of checking the image equity:

```
private void pictureBox94_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBox3.Checked)
    {
        pictureBox94.Image = Properties.Resources.select;
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox94.Image = Properties.Resources.vuoto;
    }

    checkBox3.Checked = !checkBox3.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is, that `Properties.Resources.vuoto` is implemented as a call to `ResourceManager.GetObject` (just select it and hit `F12` to see the implementation in `Resources.Designer.cs`), and this call returns a different image instance each time called. Therefore, your `if` condition is always false.

You can simply test this behaviour by showing the result of

```
(Properties.Resources.vuoto == Properties.Resources.vuoto)
```

which also always return `false`.

So, the easiest way to solve your problem would be to test for the `checkBox3.Checked` property in your `if` condition as

```
if (!checkBox3.Checked) {
  pictureBox94.Image = Properties.Resources.select;
  checkBox3.Checked = true;
} else {
  pictureBox94.Image = Properties.Resources.vuoto;
  checkBox3.Checked = false;
}
```

Other solutions would be to "cache" the image in object attributes (i.e. create attributes `vuoto` and `select` in your `Form` class and set them once in your constructor), or having an additional boolean flag attribute to store the current state.